# Pattern Matching, FullForm and DisplayForm

Tags: pattern-matching

Has anybody an explanation for the following or is it a bug?
The display form and the input form do not give the same result.

[image: screenshot]

I include the raw display form here. Simply copy it to Mathematica to inspect it.
The two following two pattern match:

```
MatchQ[
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(_\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"_", ",", "_"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]]

MatchQ[
 Derivative[0, 1][Subscript[u, 2]][x1, x2] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(_\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"_", ",", "_"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]   
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(_\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"_", ",", "_"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]]
```

However if I change the first derivative from Fullform to Displayform, that is: Derivative[0,1][u2] to u2^(0,1), the pattern does no more match:

```
MatchQ[
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(_\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"_", ",", "_"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\) [x1, x2] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(_\)], 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"_", ",", "_"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]]
```

Comment: The second and third examples are not equivalent since a derivative has been reversed (0, 1) to (1, 0) -- but the question draws out an interesting issue just the same.

Answer (score 6):

**Summary**

The exhibited behaviour is correct.  In the last example, the expression under test is an inert expression of the form `Derivative[...] * Derivative[...]`.  But the pattern evaluates to the form `Derivative[...]^2`.  These two forms do not match.  The fix is to use `HoldPattern` to prevent the pattern from evaluating.  When doing this kind of work, it probably would not hurt to hold the test expression `Unevaluated` as well.

**Details**

To make it easier to see what is happening, we will work with `InputForm` throughout.

*First Example*

The first example is straight-forward:

```
MatchQ[
  Derivative[1,0][x1,x2]
, Derivative[_,_][x1,x2]
]

(* True *)
```

*Second Example*

The second example seems to be straight-forward as well:

```
MatchQ[
  Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]
, Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]*Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]
]

(* True *)
```

... but the route to this result might be a little surprising.  `MatchQ` does not hold its arguments, so both the test expression and the pattern are evaluated before they are compared:

```
Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]
(* Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]^2 *)

Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]*Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]
(* Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]^2 *)
```

Lucky for us, these evaluated forms are still structural matches:

```
MatchQ[
  Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]^2
, Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]^2
]

(* True *)
```

*Third Example*

In the third example, we are not so lucky:

```
MatchQ[
  Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[1,0][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]
, Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]*Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]
]

(* False *)
```

Because the expression under test is a product of derivatives that are taken with respect to different variables, it does not evaluate to the form `... ^ 2`.  But the pattern does:

```
Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[1,0][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]
(* Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[1,0][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2] *)

Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1, x2]*Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]    
(* Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]^2 *)
```

So the forms that we are actually matching are manifestly different:

```
MatchQ[
  Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[1,0][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]
, Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]^2
]

(* False *)
```

*Fix*

The fix is to ensure that the pattern is not evaluated prior to use.  We can use `HoldPattern`:

```
MatchQ[
              Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[1,0][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]
, HoldPattern[Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]*Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]]
]

(* True *)
```

Depending upon the application, it may be desirable to prevent the test expression from evaluating as well.  If so, `Unevaluated` might be a convenient choice:

```
MatchQ[
  Unevaluated[Derivative[0,1][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]*Derivative[1,0][Subscript[u,2]][x1,x2]]
, HoldPattern[Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]*Derivative[_,_][Subscript[u,_]][x1,x2]]
]

(* True *)
```

Other methods to prevent evaluation are available, but they are beyond the scope of this response.

*Display Forms*

All of these results shown here using `InputForm` will be the same if we work in display forms as well.  For example:

[image: display form screenshot]